# nomenclature of organic compounds?

Tags: nomenclature

Is it necessary for a chain of compound to have a functional group or they can be named without a functional group?I know that the longest continous chain must be selected for naming ,but I found a quote which was saying that the longest chain with afunctional group ,"if present" must be chosen to  be named it confused me about the necessity of functional group?

Comment: What would you think will happen if you try to name a compound without any functional groups (BTW, yes, such compounds do exist)? Will the world go down with error 500?

Comment: I personally not aware of such compounds and I think it would be difficult to name a compound without a functional group

Comment: On the contrary, this is by far the easiest case, hence all textbooks start with it. Are you reading yours from the middle?

Comment: No ,this topic is not included in my textbook ,I find a quote in my mcqs book

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that, if you have a compound like this:

[image]

You must name it as

> 4-propylnonan-3-ol

taking the chain having $\ce{-OH}$ instead of

> 4-(1'-hydroxypropyl)nonane

Comment: To add to this answer (+1): if a compound does **not** have any functional group, just don't worry about its absence, and take the longest possible carbon chain.

Comment: The alternative name "4-(1'-hydroxypropyl)nonane" is not correct. Even if you would not express the $\ce{-OH}$ group as a suffix, it would still be "3-hydroxy-4-propylnonane".